# Consuming PATCH API in java(Earlier question have been removed)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I have to consume PATCH API in java. When I am trying to use in the below code it is giving exception

```
  java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(Unknown Source)
    at com.java.jackson.jackson.PatchRequest.main(PatchRequest.java:32)
```

this line in below code throwing the exception.

```
connection.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
```

I am using below code for the same.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import com.eclipsesource.json.Json;
import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;

public class PatchRequest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection connection=null;
            String targetUrl="https://xxxxxxxxx-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/"+botID+"/dynamicEntities/"+dynamicEntityId+"/pushRequests/"+pushRequestId+"/values";
            URL url=new URL(targetUrl);
            connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches (false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+"eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6IjZhYnBycWVsRl9ld3NEaW1HRy0wY0JpNVg2N09jQjkzTGNyN2Y4M3UzLXMiLCJ4NXQiOiJkdlhSRXBGdXpTenRMdGlMM2Vmbk1rbVo0Rk0iLCJraWQiOiJTSUdOSU5HX0tFWSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.j2tQr_lS5DNwzRuttsDKxDMYoiGreFVfe-rs-TmRF1gN5VDmNcnKnw5WWh8yL73ixrNtoELbY5h7uRyB49vCMPHiUtIMRYL8yXGfn56VOJvxshQAVjfCrMyGS6FeTlnuR-4CLEwy_QYWXV3CX7JRN2cVbYapwS1Nex9KX0wrF-tMmgEEttBsQxDlc6BqwacCtFBVjKvZTyhucivjQCfMhFINeMtL3ktqs1e3_ztundyiWV6vjDgrGjVY5UatHLqdorTC0Q56GVi3OPIAKisDUAP7vtnaeuaLR9aARwPVDFLcY6gMjsOWMYCfAHkAZ7RBkuLsptxUc3czUXfqMLxqtw");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");    
            osw.write("\"{\\n    \\\"delete\\\": [\\n    \\n        {\\n            \\\"canonicalName\\\": \\\"FTE Discrete Org\\\"\\n        } \\n    ],\\n    \\\"modify\\\": [\\n        {\\n            \\\"canonicalName\\\": \\\"FTE Process Org\\\",\\n            \\\"synonyms\\\": [\\n                \\\"FTE Process Org\\\",\\\"FTE Process  Org\\\",\\\"fteprocessorg\\\"\\n            ]\\n        }\\n    ],\\n    \\n     \\\"add\\\": [        \\n\\n        {\\n            \\\"canonicalName\\\": \\\"Vision Canada\\\",\\n            \\\"synonyms\\\": [\\n                \\\"visioncanada\\\",\\n                \\\"vision  canada\\\",\\\"vision canada\\\"\\n            ]\\n        },\\n        {\\n            \\\"canonicalName\\\": \\\"apple computers\\\",\\n            \\\"synonyms\\\": [\\n                \\\"apple corp\\\",\\n                \\\"apple\\\"             \\n            ]\\n        }\\n    ]\\n}\"");
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
            os.close(); 
            System.out.println("Code works before connect");

            connection.connect();
            
            System.out.println("Code works after connect");
            int responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response code:"+responseCode);
            if (responseCode==401) {
                System.out.println("Unauthorized Error");
            } else if(responseCode==200) {       
                InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(in);
                String output;
                String apiOutput="";
                while((output=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    apiOutput+=output;
                }
                System.out.println(apiOutput);  
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I read in google and then I replaced the line which throws exception by below 2 lines.

```
connection.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

then it throws `Http status code 412`. Can you please help me on the same.

Comment: can you please include the entire stack trace from the exception you get

Comment: Hi @Jocke I have added the code. line number might be different because i removed some confidential details before putting the code here.

Comment: Great. Have a look here. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to do that with `java.net.HttpURLConnection` see details in link below. You need to use the Client API in the `java.net.http` package.

Detail can be found here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8207840